# how do i use this route output to my index page between h3 tags

Tags: php, database, html, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

my web.php

```
Route::get('/index',function()
{

    $count_total = DB::table('vendors')->count('id');

    return  $count_total;
});
```

in my index.blade.php

```
<h3>  </h3>

<p>Vendors</p>
```

Comment: please have a quick look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this

```
Route::get('/index',function()
{

    $count_total = DB::table('vendors')->count('id');

    return view('index',compact('count_total'));
});
```

Then In your index.blade.php

```
<h3> {{$count_total}} </h3>

<p>Vendors</p>
```

Comment: thank for your help sapnesh..but i m receiving this error "Undefined variable: count_total" on index page..i tried this before also but i got his same...is there any way to solve this

Comment: Route::get('/indexs',function()    wheh i rename as index to indexs the page is fetching...but when i rename to index ..it shows "Undefined variable: count_total"

Comment: @Veekee45 post all of your routes

Comment: i added the code to the controller and called the controller by routes and it worked perfectly...thankyou so much for your great help...well done bro keep it up..

Comment: @Veekee45 Thanks! You can accept the answer if it helped you

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('index', ['count_total' => $count_total]);
});
```

in index.blade.php

```
<h3> {{$count_total}} </h3>

<p>Vendors</p>
```

Comment: hi Bilal thanks for your reply...but i want this output to shown between the h3 tags in my index ....how do i link this out put example <h3>{{ i need this output here... please help }}</h3>

Comment: @Veekee45 i have update my answer.. and also you can echo like this ... <h3><?php echo $count_total; ?>

Comment: i added the code to the controller and called the controller by routes and it worked perfectly...thankyou so much for your great help...well done bro keep it up..